# How to get rid of 'Json file Import Error' in Python while using request.data?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas

Json file Import Error Python: I am using request.data to request a json file but getting the following error:

> Extra data: line 1 column 13 - line 12 column 2 (char 12 - 1388)

My Json file looks like this:

```
"items":  
[{"ItemId":"1","EntityCode": "A", "Title": "abc","date":"2017-09-01"},   
{"ItemId":"2","EntityCode": "A", "Title": "cba","date":"2017-09-01"},  
{"ItemId":"3","EntityCode": "A", "Title": "bcd","date":"2017-09-01"}]
```

This is my input which I will get as data in following code: 
    `data=request.data`

I also used  https://jsonlint.com/ to validate this json but it says

> Error: Parse error on line 1: "items":

This data is coming from a java application how can i resolve this? Please feel free to revert back with further queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try

```
{"items":  
[{"ItemId":"1","EntityCode": "A", "Title": "abc","date":"2017-09-01"},   
{"ItemId":"2","EntityCode": "A", "Title": "cba","date":"2017-09-01"},  
{"ItemId":"3","EntityCode": "A", "Title": "bcd","date":"2017-09-01"}]}
```

Without bracket it's not a valid json.

Did you try request.json instead of request.data ? If you can't correct your json file you can also try data = "{{{0}}}".format(request.data)

Answer (score 0):

A valid JSON will have the curly braces to begin with, so your `data=request.data` should return

```
{
"items": [{
        "ItemId": "1",
        "EntityCode": "A",
        "Title": "abc",
        "date": "2017-09-01"
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "2",
        "EntityCode": "A",
        "Title": "cba",
        "date": "2017-09-01"
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "3",
        "EntityCode": "A",
        "Title": "bcd",
        "date": "2017-09-01"
    }
]
}
```

Validated from the site you mentioned in OP. Try the above JSON in JSONLint website.

Comment: Is there a way I can put this up after I request data.
As in can I make this correction in python?

Comment: Yes, you can simply make it a dictionary.

If you just want the 'items', then you could do as `items = {'items':request.data['items']}` , but isn't `request.data` already giving you a dictionary, or, if you want the JSON data from the client, then you can simply call `request.json` instead of `request.data` and then get your items, just like you do with a normal dictionary